# PHP Get Last Data ID

Tags: php, html

I want the last data to have `margin-bottom: 0px;`

### functions.php

```
$SQL_7 = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT * FROM users");
$row_number = mysqli_num_rows($SQL_7);
$i = 1;

while ($Fetch_7 = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL_7)) {                 

    // If last row remove margin bottom
    if ($i < $row_number) {
        $get_margin = "style='margin-bottom: 0px;'";
    }
}
```

### index.php

```
<div class='margin_bottom_10' <?php echo $get_margin; ?> >
    Test
</div>
```

### Example

```
 <div id='data1' class='margin_bottom_10'>Test</div>
<div id='data2' class='margin_bottom_10'>Test</div>
<div id='data3' class='margin_bottom_10' style='margin-bottom: 0px;'>Test</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to change your `if` statement to be something like this `if($i == $row_number)` do your stuff.

Comment: You need to increment $i somewhere inside while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should increment $i whilst in the while loop. `$i++` adds one to the variable. You want this to match your row count as that will be the last record. If you have 10 users, after 10 loops $i will equal 10 and then your clause will add the style tag.

```
<?php
$SQL_7 = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT * FROM users");
$row_number = mysqli_num_rows($SQL_7);
$i = 0;

while ($Fetch_7 = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL_7)) {                 
    // increment i
    $i++;

    // If last row remove margin bottom
    if ($i == $row_number) {
        $get_margin = "style='margin-bottom: 0px;'"; // Do show
    } else {
        $get_margin = ""; // Dont show
    }
}
```

Edit: Better start with zero!

Comment: with your code result is :

 <div id='data1' class='margin_bottom_10'>Test</div>
<div id='data2' class='margin_bottom_10' style='margin-bottom: 0px;'>Test</div>
<div id='data3' class='margin_bottom_10' style='margin-bottom: 0px;'>Test</div>


i want only last row with style='margin-bottom: 0px;'

Comment: try: `$i++; if ($i == $row_number) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

`increment` `$i` by when in each step and whenever `$i= num_of_row` assing `$get_margin` required `margin`

```
    `$SQL_7 = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT * FROM users");
    $row_number = mysqli_num_rows($SQL_7);
    $i = 1;

    while ($Fetch_7 = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL_7)) {                 

        // If last row remove margin bottom
        if ($i ==  $row_number) 
            $get_margin = "style='margin-bottom: 0px;'";


            $i++;
    }
    ?>
    <div id='data1' class='margin_bottom_10'>Test</div>
    <div id='data2' class='margin_bottom_10'>Test</div>
    <div id='data3' class='margin_bottom_10' <?php  echo $get_margin; ?>>Test</div>`
```